# Check if a collectionViewCell is showing more than 50% on collectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

i got a UICollectionView with (3*3 Grid), so when i scroll up and down, is there a way i can detect if the collection view cell is displaying more than 50% of its height on the screen?

```
let visibleRect = CGRect(origin: collectionView.contentOffset, size: collectionView.bounds.size)
let visiblePoint = CGPoint(x: visibleRect.minX, y: visibleRect.midY)
let visibleIndexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: visiblePoint)
```

I have tried this but it doesn't seems to work. Does anyone has solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask for

```
@property(nonatomic) CGPoint contentOffset;
```

of UIScrollView because UICollectionView's inherits from them.

and don't forget your Cell's have a CALayer that knows the visible Rectangle as well.

```
CGRect visiblerect = cell.layer.visibleRect;
if (visiblerect.size.height > (cell.frame.size.height * 0.5)) {
    // do stuff when cell is more visible then half its size
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, yah i know contentOffset, but how do i check if a cell is displaying on screen more than 50%?

Comment: when you know cell's frame.size.height and the margin around the cells, the collectionView.contentSize; you can even ask UICollectionView-visibleCells and do simple math.

Comment: haha. sorry edited my answer. its a objC.. easy to translate to swift. i think

Comment: ah, great i got the big idea of how it works now Thanks! 
One more thing, i was trying with cell.layer.visibleRect, but for cell that is showing less than 50%, it always return me the actual height of the cell?